# Notification Center gets called but value of UILabel is not updated in IOS

Tags: ios, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I am using push notifications in my code and whenever a notification comes, I want to update the value of a label in another ViewController.

My code in AppDelegate is:

```
- (void)addMessageFromRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo updateUI:(BOOL)updateUI
{
    NSLog(@"Notification arrived");
    //[mydeals setCode1_id:mydeals.code1_id withString:@"123456"];
    mydeals=[[MyDealsViewController alloc]init];
    NSDictionary* codeDetails=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"123456",@"Code_id", nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CodeArrived" object:self userInfo:codeDetails];
}
```

then in my other view controller I have this code:

```
@implementation MyDealsViewController

-(id) init
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveCode:)
                                                 name:@"CodeArrived"
                                               object:nil];
    return self;
}

-(void) receiveCode:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"received Code: %@",notification.userInfo);
    self.code1_id.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"Code_id"]];
}
```

the log is printed correctly but when I manually go into that screen I see the default value, like the label is not updated at all. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that when you "manually go" to `MyDealsViewController`, whatever how you do it, it got to be the same instance of `MyDealsViewController` wich has been called `receiveCode`. Otherwise it's going to init with it's default values.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try calling [self.code1_id setNeedsLayout];